# Use external file storage for heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cpanel

I have rails application running on heroku, as heroku file system is read-only so we cannot store any files or images on heroku.

A lot of people has suggested to use amazon s3, but can i use external storage to save user files and images and to retrieve them from there with paperclip or carrier-wave or anything similar.

Currently i am using Dropbox for images and files storage. But its too slow. I have a shared hosting account, there i have a lot of disk space and i want to use that to store files.
Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by CPanel storage?

Comment: i have purchased a shared hosting account and on cpanel they have given me some storage space. what should i say to it?

Comment: That is different. If what I'm thinking is right, you are not allowed to do file host in most of the shared hosting.